# VBA - Struggling with worksheet_change. Not working with no error given

Tags: vba

I have a sheet in which our wholesale team are to enter [L09 Part Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z635t.png) and quickly see how much we have in stock of that item. The problem is that new starters may struggle to learn these part numbers as they don't follow a simple rule. What I did was create an easier code to remember which is simply: "Cable Type" & "Core Size" & "Cut Length", they also have the option to add "Colour" and "Brand" separated by spaces.
Their entered string may look like 6242y 2.5 100, or maybe 6242y 2.5 100 Grey, etc. and so where to look in my mapped table for what they've written depends on how many terms they put in. As you can see from the attached picture I need to select the correct column to look in for their code, and then offset back a few columns to suggest the correct L09 Part Number.

I hope the context makes a bit of sense and helps with the below code. The idea was for a new starter to enter something simple and it be replaced before their very eyes...
If anyone could help me to correct the following it would be greatly appreciated:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim P, Products, S, Search As Range
Dim Column As String
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim Spaces As Long

'On Error Resume Next

Counter = 0

'For top table only
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row < 100 Then

    'Count spaces
    Spaces = UBound(Split(Target, " "), 1)

    Select Case Spaces

        Case Is = 2
            Column = "M"

        Case Is = 3
            Column = "O"

        Case Is = 4
            Column = "Q"

    End Select

    'When string has spaces
    If Spaces <> 0 Then

    'Set simple code range
    Set Search = Sheets("Cherries").Range(Column & 1 & ":" & Column & 10000)

        For Each S In Search

            If S = Target Then

                Target = S.Offset(0, 3 - 2 * Spaces)

            End If

        Next S

    End If

    Set Products = Sheets("Order Entry").Range("A3:A99")

    For Each P In Products

        If P.Value <> "" Then

            Counter = Counter + 1

        End If

    Next P

    Sheets("Order Entry").Rows("3:" & Counter + 11).Hidden = False

    Sheets("Order Entry").Rows(Counter + 11 & ":99").Hidden = True

End If

End Sub
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure which line is erroring as no error message is given.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: 1. Does it compile? 2. Does it execute? 3. Your variables `P, Products, S` are implicitly declared `As Variant` - you need to add `As Range` for each one of them separately.

Comment: It does compile and I can't tell if it executes or not. When I type in a code that appears in one of those columns shown, nothing happens. The string is just left unchanged in the cell. I edited my declarations and split them into separate lines and it hasn't made a difference. To be honest I didn't know that there was a difference - I thought it was just to group them together to make it quicker to type.

Comment: I should add that it does work for strings with no spaces involved, i.e. they are unchanged and the sheet works as expected. Also on the column and row restriction, I am entering codes into cells A3:A5 as a test.

Comment: Put the statement `Debug.Print "Worksheet_Change: " & Target.Address` at the top of that procedure to see if anything happens. The output (if any) will appear in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).

Comment: Also, what does the line `?Application.EnableEvents` as entered into the Immediate window result in?

Comment: Hi again, I entered that at the top of the code and the immediate change was 
"Worksheet_Change: $A$5". Your second line returned True.

Comment: Then the event procedure is invoked and working. Set a breakpoint at the beginning, and step through it with F8. Hovering the mouse pointer over variable names will show you their current value. (Optionally enable the *Locals* window from the View menu, to get an overview of all variables + their values in the current scope.) Follow the control flow too see where the actual behavior diverges from your intentions.

Comment: Obviously, the event routine is triggered. Simply set a breakpoint (F9)  to the beginning of your code, enter something in the sheet to trigger the routine and step to your code to check what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm not familiar with breakpoints and testing through the code but that sounds very helpful! I'm giving it a go and looking at the variable values that it has calculated - they all look great so far. For a string with three terms it has correctly found 2 spaces and calculated Column = "M". Looking at the Search range it has also found the Column property = 13 ("M") so I can't figure it out just yet.

Comment: I can't solve it! Been stuck for hours looking at this and I really just don't understand :(

Comment: I think you then need to [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53334870/edit) your question. What is working and what isn't? **Most importantly**: What are the inputs, what does the expected outcome look like and what is the *actual* outcome? Be as specific as possible. (I.e. "it's not working" is about as unspecific as it can get.)